# Adding a subproject at top level

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

When I add a subproject to a master project, it always becomes a part of the project just above it. It is indented one more level.

Must I only create subprojects on the top row of the project?

Using the Outdent Task icon and Ctrl-Shift-Left have no effect. How can I outdent the subproject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collapse all summary tasks before inserting subprojects and they will be inserted at outline level 1.

Note: only the project summary task is at level 0.